# Having trouble checking if a directory exists shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I've made an if statement (shown below) to check if a directory exists and if not, create that directory, however every time I run it it cannot find the directory even if it does exist, then produces an error when trying to create it because it already exists!!

Can somebody please help!!

```
cd $HOME
if [-d user_records]
then
    echo "user_records already exists!"
else
    mkdir user_records
fi
```

Comment: add a space before -d

Answer (score 2):

You just missed a space:

```
if [ -d user_records]
# --^--
```